# /tmp and /var/tmp as tmpfs and volatility

Tags: security, tmpfs, tmp, conventions

> The use of separate file systems for different paths can protect the system from failures resulting from a file system becoming full or failing.
>
> Check that a file system/partition has been created for "/var/tmp"

For a while I have done `systemctl enable tmp.mount` which makes `/tmp` mounted as a tmpfs {ram} file system, with zero problems.  Given RHEL, or Linux, provides a `systemctl` to enable that {*it's not a hack job*} I have to believe they knew what they were doing.

In `/etc/fstab` **after** the disk partitioning has been done and RHEL 8.8 has been installed and running and `/var/tmp` would be located under the `/` physical disk partition, if I do

```
tmpfs   /var/tmp    tmpfs    defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec,size=1G   0  0
```

- What is the convention for the use of the `/var/tmp` folder?
- Why didn't they offer a `systemctl enable var-tmp.mount` ?
- If `/var/tmp` gets cleared after every reboot, does that pose a problem?
- I opted to specify a 1 GB max size, rather than let it be an automated choice that shows up as 94GB via `df -h`, but looking at other RHEL 7 & 8 systems I don't see much more than 20 MB present there.  How much should be expected to be found in `/var/tmp`?  What are some various things this folder is used for?

  - I only see `kdecache-<user>` folders, license lock files, `systemd-private-abc123-various.service` folders, and `yum` folders.  Specifically interested in RHEL 8.8, not so much RHEL 7.9 anymore.
- Was there a security related positive with doing `/tmp` as tmpfs?  Is there a similar positive with doing `/var/tmp` as tmpfs as well?  Shouldn't everybody be doing this?