# will DNF [YUM] fail if /var/tmp is a tmpfs file system?

Tags: yum, dnf, tmpfs, fhs

I was considering making `/var/tmp` a `tmpfs` mount, similar to *systemctl enable tmp.mount* in order to meet a security rule requesting `/var/tmp` be on a separate partition.  I did not make that physical partition at linux install time.

> The FHS (File hierarchy standard) states *The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that require temporary files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore, data stored in /var/tmp is more persistent than data in /tmp.*

Specifically, for RHEL 8.8 or later, can having `/var/tmp` as a `tmpfs` (where it will be cleared after every reboot), cause a **yum update** to fail?  Is YUM [DNF] in RHEL 8 once of those *programs*?  If so, under what conditions would some sort of failure occur with `/var/tmp` as tmpfs?  And if so, is there a manner in which to run yum/dnf that can allow it to work with a tmpfs `/var/tmp`?  I ask because I see various `/var/tmp/yum-xxxx` folders from time to time.

reference posts:

[/tmp and /var/tmp as tmpfs and volatility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757679/tmp-and-var-tmp-as-tmpfs-and-volatility)

[What can go wrong if /var/tmp is on a temporary filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86297/what-can-go-wrong-if-var-tmp-is-on-a-temporary-filesystem)

Comment: In any case, do not do it. It is not the purpose of /var/tmp. If you think a program can work with just /tmp, file a bug, so they use /tmp instead of /var/tmp. Personally I do not think it is a problem. Persistent data should go in /var/{lib, ...}, and rest in /var/cache but we never know (and you are removing a good helper to debug problems)

Answer (score 0):

DNF won't care, it shouldn't even use this directory. I'm a little bit surprised about

> I ask because I see various /var/tmp/yum-xxxx folders from time to time.

because RHEL 8 used DNF internally. Yum exists only as a symlink to DNF.

AFAIK in RHEL 8.x `/var/tmp` is already `tmpfs` or maybe it was introduced in version 9. Anyways, it'll work.

Comment: `/var/tmp` is definitely **NOT** tmpfs in RHEL 8.8.

Comment: RHEL9 that is, then. It should work regardless like I said. `/var/tmp` was designated to survive reboots but in practice it's OK to wipe it clean on each reboot/power cycle. The important volatile data must be stored elsewhere regardless. `/tmp|/var/tmp|/dev/shm` are the three directories that contain truly transient data.

Comment: if RHEL 9 actually does `/var/tmp` as a `tmpfs` how can you claim that it will be ok in RHEL 8?  I said I see `/var/tmp/yum-xxx` folders there in RHEL 8.8 (as I have in RHEL 7.9) and you're telling me *it shouldn't even use this directory*?  And, you say */var/tmp was designed to survive reboots* which I can believe and won't disagree with but that's the point of my question if I tmpfs /var/tmp will I be creating a problem for "DNF" in RHEL 8?

Comment: Your question is **not** upgrading from RHEL8 to 9 so I'm 100% sure you'll have no issues with `/var/tmp` as a `tmpfs`.